# unable to change the IP address on Ubuntu server 17

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu server and put IP address while installation,but now I need to change it and unable to find the file network file location on ssh and graphically.

anyone has idea to change ens160(interface name) ip address.

below is the some output for your information

```
root@ubuntu:~# nmcli con show
NAME  UUID  TYPE  DEVICE

root@ubuntu:~# nmcli con mod "Wired connection 1"
Error: unknown connection 'Wired connection 1'.
```

Comment: Usually this is done in `/etc/network/interfaces`. How does yours look like?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `lsb_release -d` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `nmtui(NetworkManager TUI)`?
Open nmtui with root privileges,
You'll see ncurses prompt, use tab key for navigation.
Select edit a connection,
Select the Network interface you want to edit, and select edit,
There you will find profile name,
Change the name as per your needs
After selecting edit, you'll see IPv4 configuration it might me set to automatic. Set it to manual, and select show,
In addresses field, input desired IP address,
Provide gateway, and DNS Server address,
And select ok.
You would return to interface section,
Select back, exit NMTUI,
And restart Network

Answer (score 0):

**Until Ubuntu Server 17.04.** this is usually done in `/etc/network/interfaces`

There you should have an entry block for this interface like that

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
      address <IP you want to have>
      netmask <your netmask e.g. 255.255.255.0>
      gateway <ip of the router to the internet>
      dns-nameservers: <e.g. 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4>
```

For more options look at [the interfaces manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/interfaces.5.html) and [the network configuration manpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

**In Ubuntu Server 17.10 this changed**

See the example from [this tutorial](https://websiteforstudents.com/switch-static-ip-address-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/)

`/etc/netplan`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system 
# For more information, see netplan(5).     
network: 
     version: 2 
     renderer: networkd 
     ethernets: 
         ens33: 
             dhcp4: no 
             dhcp6: no 
             addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]  
             gateway4: 192.168.1.1 
             nameservers: 
                 addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

and the [netplan manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/netplan.5.html)

Comment: No DNS nameservers?? Is /etc/network/interfaces correct for Server 17.10?

Comment: No but he didn't say 17.10. only 17 and the question is about changing an IP not about changing DNS nameservers...

Comment: Nice save. You're welcome.